# In SQL, I want to get some output using Query, but have no Idea how to make it

Tags: sql

I want to get some output for which author is the most popular for readers.
So, first table has columns such as

```
BibNum  Title   Author  ISBN    PublicationYear Publisher   Subjects    ItemType    ItemCollection  FloatingItem    ItemLocation    ReportDate  ItemCount
```

As a  referrence, BibNum is account number of readers.

And second table has information such as

```
BibNum  ItemBarcode ItemType    Collection  CallNumber  CheckoutDateTime
```

How I can make some query for getting the answer from problem I mentioned? 
Please enlighten me with any helps.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your tables have no obvious columns that related to "readers", so I'm voting to close the question as unclear.

Comment: select count(distinct title, author) from drivers group by BibNum for this query I wanted to check how many books are present by author and SELECT d.Title, d.author t.ItemType, t.CheckoutDatetime where (d.driverId = t.driverId); and I tried this query too

Comment: @GordonLinoff , No BibNum is the account number for reader. Sorry I didn't mention it . I will edit it